# How to intercept POST request when multiple requests are being made in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

In my Cypress test, I am trying to intercept a request when logging in.

The password value I am passing to the request is `9K%bZKR8`.

What I have observed is that when I click the login button, 2 POST requests are being made:

[image]

The 1st request contains the correct password `9K%bZKR8`,

I have tried listening for this, but the test times out, saying `No request ever occurred.`.

I even tried hard-coding the URL like below, but I keep getting the above error:

```
cy.intercept('POST', `**/Users/Login?username=****&password=9K%bZKR8`).as('LoginRequest')
```

The 2nd request for some reason contains a different password value - `9K%25bZKR8`. I'm not sure where the `25` is coming from here.

I also hard-coded the URL here & it is being picked up somehow:

```
cy.intercept('POST', `**/Users/Login?username=****&password=9K%25bZKR8`).as('LoginRequest')
```

I could use the 2nd request & assert on that response, but I would have thought it is better to use the 1st request as that contains the correct password.

Can someone please tell me why the 2 requests are occuring, & how I can assert on the 1st one?

Comment: Can you show your complete code for your intercept, actions to trigger the request, and the wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theory is the `%25` in `9K%25bZKR8` is the URL escape code for the literal char `%` in the typed-in string.

See [URL Encoding Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) - type in `%` and it gives back `%25`.

To intercept, I would shorten the URL and use javascript inside the callback to match the query string section (i.e `&password=9K%bZKR8`)

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '**/Users/Login', (req) => {    // anything going to Login
  if (req.query.password === '9K%bZKR8') {
    req.continue(res => {
      console.log(res)        // check the response
    })
  if (req.query.password === '9K%25bZKR8') {
    req.continue(res => {
      console.log(res)        // check the response
    })
  }

})
```